# Linux is getting slow after some Python-sessions

Tags: python, linux, performance, numpy

I may have a "weird" question. I'm using, linux MINT and python, after some "sessions", I think Linux is getting realy slow. I abort sometimes a python script, cause I see it is going wrong or something else. If I restart my computer, it is going fast as I know it...

Same for some other iterations steps: for example:

```
for test in tests:
    os.system("python code.py "+something[i][0]+" "+something[i][1]+" 3 "+test+" usage")
```

At Iteration 2 or 3, the code is getting more slow. Is it possible, that I'm using some numpy array not correctly? Or is there a possibility that python doesn't delete the "last" seassion and it is sill working or saved in the "background" from Linux? Sorry if the question is a little bit "bad", dont  now the behaviour of python.

Tried it on Linux Mint and Ubuntu on 2 computers.

My Computer:

Xeon E3-1231 v3, 16GB DDR3,

MCVE

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

target=int(sys.argv[3])

method=sys.argv[4]

vs=sys.argv[5]
```

def manu(test,test2):
    #split to X and y
    X=[]
    y=[]

```
for i,j in enumerate(test):
    X.append(test[i][0])
    y.append(float(test[i][1]))
x=np.array(X)
y=np.array(y)



pRF={ 
'class_weight':['balanced_subsample'],
'n_estimators':treeRange,
'max_features':['sqrt'],
'min_samples_leaf':[1,2,3]}
classifiers=[RandomForestClassifier(random_state=1)]
paraCV=[pRF]
titles=['RF']

for name, clf, parCV in zip(titles,classifiers,paraCV):

    fol=10
    skf = StratifiedKFold(y, n_folds=fol)
    pre,sen,spe,ba,area,params,scores=[],[],[],[],[],[],[]
    #outer loop
    for train_index, test_index in skf:
        #inner loop    
        #print train_index, test_index
        predi=[]
        train=train_index.tolist()
        test=test_index.tolist()
        X_train=[]
        X_test=[]
        y_train=[]
        y_test=[]
        for i in train:
            X_train.append(x[i])    
        for i in test:
            X_test.append(x[i]) 

        for i in train:
            y_train.append(y[i])

        for i in test:
            y_test.append(y[i]) 
        gs = GridSearchCV(estimator=clf,param_grid=parCV,cv=fol,n_jobs=5).fit(X_train,y_train)  

        expected= [0.0 if z==2.0 else z for z in y_test]
        predicted=gs.predict_proba(X_test)
        predicted1= predicted[:,0].tolist()
        params.append(gs.best_params_)
        expi=expected
        expected=np.array(expected)

        # and so on.. code would be way to long for an MCVE

if __name__=="__main__": 


    train=sys.argv[1]
    test=sys.argv[2]
```

and this code will be for example 5 times executed with an another python file like I mentioned at the beginning with the os.system order.

It seems, that is only happening on Linux, not on windows.

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example ?

Comment: I added something, but dont now if thes realy helps. It's generell that after a lot of pythons "starts" or "aborts" for example after 50... Linux is going slower. If Im starting the control-center to look at the Tasks, there are also 10 python seassions.. 4 of them are used ( cause of parallelization ) and the other 6 are not used from the CPU.

Comment: Could you fix your indentation please? What happens to the resources used by your Python process while that code is executing (CPU, memory)? You could check this using `htop`, for example.